# MPMoviePlayerViewController doesn't auto-rotate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm having some strange behavior where my `MPMoviePlayerViewController` isn't `auto`-rotating when the `orientation` changes. However, I recreated the same view hierarchy in a fresh project and when the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` player was up, it rotated to every orientation. I've scoured the project looking for anything that might be setting the orientation explicitly, but there is nothing.

I'll lay out all the relevant information here and the things that I've tried so far.

The view hierarchy currently looks like this:

- **Navigation Controller**
- **"Root" View Controller** <- navigation controller's 'rootViewController'
- **"Feed" View Controller** <- Pushed on the navigation stack by the Root VC
- **"Preview" View Controller** <- Presented as a modal VC from the Feed
- **MPMoviePlayerViewController Subclass** <- presented by the Feed VC via 'presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated'

Every class in the view hierarchy responds to shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation with YES only for UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait.

Things I've tried:

- Manually sending the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` up stack from the "Root" VC up to the `MPMoviePlayerViewController`
- Overriding the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` subclass' implementation of `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` to return YES for both landscape orientations *and* YES for all orientations.
- Setting 'Supported Device Orientation' in the project's summary tab.
- Calling the `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated` from other VCs like the Feed VC

If the movie player properly rotates in a fresh project with same view hierarchy, what could possible be getting in the way here. Any ideas as to where the orientation might be getting stuck?

Comment: An application using a UINavigationController (or UITabBarController) only rotates if **all** displayable (stacked / tabbed) viewControllers agree to the rotation. In your case, make sure the MPMoviePlayerViewController subclass is actually returning `YES` in all cases when being asked in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`.

Comment: @Till I certainly understand that, but as i said: In a test project with the same view hierarchy, where all the views agree on one rotation (portrait), the movie player rotated to every orientation without a problem.  

   Edit: The latter part of your response was answered under "Things I tried" in my question. Thanks!

Comment: right, please check my edited comment as I initially did not fully understand your UI hierarchy.

Comment: Ow, you mentioned YES for landscape only - not YES for all orientations.

Comment: @Till Thanks, I accidentally left that part out of my question so I edited it. I did indeed try both landscape and ALL orientations.

Comment: Overall it appears to be a very localized problem - especially since you did the right thing already; trying to recreate the issue in a minimal project. As you fail to recreate the issue in that minimal project scenario, your issue obviously resides within the differences of both projects. 
If I were in your situation, I would **very** closely look at your `MPMoviePlayerViewController` subclass and at the presenting viewController ("Preview"). If all of that fails, go higher within the VC hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

For anyone that might encounter this, the reason the video wasn't rotating was that I was accidentally adding the RootViewController has the window's rootViewController, rather than the UINavigationController.

```
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

is correct

`self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;`

is not

Thank you guys for your help and input along the way.

Answer (score 7):

I will suggest you not to use `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated`, rather than add as subview. I think it will fix your problem nicely.

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpviewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                    initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.filePath]];
[self.view addSubview:mpviewController.view];
[self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
```

And remove the `mpviewController.view` when `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` detected. Let me see your success...

Comment: Good thinking, but this did not work :-(. Later I will retry recreating the test project not only with the identical view hierarchy but with the same classes I have on production. Will keep it updated -- thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've found that `MPMoviePlayerViewController` objects will honor the project's Info.plist settings for supported interface orientations. In a project of mine I was only allowing landscape views in that file so the movie player will not rotate, even when it answered `YES` to landscape orientations in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`.

Edit: OK, grasping at straws: Do you implement `automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers` in any of your `UIViewController` subclasses? If so, and it returns `NO`, your subclasses must forward the appropriate methods to any child controllers upon orientation change.

Otherwise is there any way to see your code?

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that didn't do it for me either. I tried setting the project-info.plist file to accept every orientation, as well as landscape only, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

I know this might be a stupid suggestion but make sure that the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method in your `MPMoviePlayerViewController` subclass is getting called. Maybe something went wrong there...

Also make sure that you don't have 2 subviews added to the main `UIWindow` as specified [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html):

> **Q:  Why won't my UIViewController rotate with the device?**
>
> [...]
>
> - The view controller's UIView property is embedded inside UIWindow but
>   alongside an additional view controller.

I think that might give you some problems too. You can find more information about what could go wrong in the link above.

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas:

- Is the `UINavigationController` set as the `rootViewController` property of your app's `UIWindow`? You didn't mention that. You should do this rather then adding the navigation controller's view to the window.
- In case you are building the entire hierarchy at once, try breaking it down. You can add a button to each stage which adds the next view controller to the hierarchy.
- Try removing any animations from the view controller hierarchy construction. Doing multiple animations at the same time could be trouble. For example, it's not allowed to push two view controllers in a `UINavigationController` one after another, with `animated:YES`. You might have  a similar issue.
- Make sure you build your entire view controller hierarchy on the main thread.
- Make sure there is no other view controller "taking charge" of the rotation (as @MihaiFratu wrote - this is so common a reason for rotation issues that I had to repeat it :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using storyboards? Compare the orientation settings for your UIViewControllers and your UINavigationController between your broken project and your test project. The "Orientation" setting on the attributes inspector may be locking you into one orientation.

You mentioned `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and your plist settings so I won't get into that...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but no storyboards in this project.

Answer (score 0):

there are some reasons behind at your query..

***You are calling `MPMoviePlayerViewController`..  so apply AutoOrientation  on `"Feed" View Controller` And try to call by PushViewController..

***Use `MPMoviePlayerController` instead of  `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and add subview in to `FeedViewController`..

Sample code for MPMoviePlayerController--

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"type"]];
videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url]; 
videoPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone; 
videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width);
[videoPlayer prepareToPlay];
videoPlayer.view.center = self.view.center;
videoPlayer.fullscreen = YES;
[self.view addSubview:videoPlayer.view];
[videoPlayer play];
```

***Check your Xcode target setting and apply enable All orientation..

Comment: And if you are using MPMoviePlayerController in viewDidLoad, than try to use in viewWillAppear..

Answer (score 0):

You should try this (Worked for me):

Declare in .h file:

```
BOOL landscape;
```

.m file:

```
-(IBAction)PlayMovie:(NSString *)movieName {
    landscape = YES;
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:movieName ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [theMovie play];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
}

-(void)dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated {
    landscape = NO;
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// You can change the return for your needs.
    if (landscape == YES) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else { return NO; }
}
```

What I did here is Creating my movie view and set the "landscape" BOOL to YES.

Then the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" will detect this and autorotate your view.

And when the movie is finished I set the "landscape" to NO so that the view rotates back.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Solved by:

1. enabling all orientations in Supported Interface Orientations (Target > Summary)
2. now your app will start rotating in all  Orientations, if you dont want this,  then skip  step 1,  only  add following method in appDelegate

   - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
     }
3. removing shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation everywhere
4. adding following method to view controller for supporting Orientations u needed for your app

   - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
     {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
     }
5. you can add the same method as in step 4 in MPMoviePlayerViewController's subclass for whatever Orientations u needed for video player

Answer (score 0):

this guide helped me checking some steps I was missing in order to allow only the video player to be viewed in landscape, leaving the rest of the application to be fixed in portrait mode:

[iOS6 and autorotation tip](http://geekanddad.wordpress.com/2012/10/20/ios-6-and-auto-rotation-tip/)

Answer (score 0):

I had lot of pain with MPMoviePlayerViewController, which should be only controller able to rotate from portrait to landscape and vice versa. It was  iOS7, iOS8 application with storyboard.

Here is solution:

1. Application should enable all possible required orientations[image: As on the image]
2. Every UIViewController that need to support just portrait mode, should implement next methods, like this

   ```
   -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
   {
       return YES;
   }

   -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
   {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
   }
   ```
3. MPMoviePlayerViewController should be extended and next methods should be overriden like this

   ```
   -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
   {
     return YES;
   }

   -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
   {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
   }
   ```
4. Use `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated` to display MPMoviePlayerViewController

Answer (score 0):

Add this method in AppDelegate.m

-(NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{

```
if(!ISIPAD)

  {

    if ([[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController]   isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]] && ![[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isBeingDismissed])

    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown ;
```

}